# Python: Adding multiple values to a dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I would like to read in a series of values from a csv file, arrange by unique key and then do some calculation on the values. So dictionary springs to mind - I can get the first value in, but am having issues with appending a second value to the same key.

The Key will be the first entry; ie the three letters, the first value to be stored will be the cumulative  addition of the values in columns 2 and 3, the second value to be stored will just be the cumulative value of column 3. So based on the file below I would like the dictionary to read:

File:

```
AAA,12.0,2

BBB,14.0,4

AAA,15.5,1
```

Output:

```
AAA:30.5,3
BBB:16.0,4
```

Sample code:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as csv_input:

    read_csv = csv.reader(csv_input)
    values = {}

    for row in read_csv:

        try:
            values[row[0]] += float(row[1]) + float(row[2])

        except KeyError:

            try:
                values[row[0]] = float(row[1]) + float(row[2])
                #values.setdefault([row[0]]).append((row[2]))

            except ValueError:

                pass
print values
```

I've tried to use the .append but cannot get it working. Any advice or tips in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `values[row[0]] = values.get(row[0], []).append(float(row[1]) + float(row[2]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you want , you are not storing a list , when you do -

```
values[row[0]] = float(row[1]) + float(row[2])
```

You should create a list of two elements, first element being the addition of `row[1]` and `row[2]` and the second being `row[2]` .

I would also suggest that you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here, and provide a function that returns a list of two elements both starting at `0` .

Example -

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('input.csv') as csv_input:
    read_csv = csv.reader(csv_input)
    values = defaultdict(lambda : [0,0])
    for row in read_csv:
        values[row[0]][0] += float(row[1]) + float(row[2])
        values[row[0]][1] += float(row[2])
print values
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> import csv
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>>
>>> with open('a.csv') as csv_input:
...     read_csv = csv.reader(csv_input)
...     values = defaultdict(lambda : [0,0])
...     for row in read_csv:
...         values[row[0]][0] += float(row[1]) + float(row[2])
...         values[row[0]][1] += float(row[2])
...
>>> print(values)
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x005B3B70>, {'AAA': [30.5, 3.0], 'BBB': [18.0, 4.0]})
```

Comment: Thank you Anand, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
import csv

with open('input.csv') as csv_input:

    read_csv = csv.reader(csv_input)
    values = {}

    for row in read_csv:

        key = row[0]
        a = float(row[1]) + float(row[2])
        b = float(row[2])

        try:
            values[key][0] += a
            values[key][1] += b

        except KeyError:

            try:
                values[key] =  list(range(2))
                values[key][0] = a
                values[key][1] = b

            except ValueError:
                pass

print(values) # {'AAA': [30.5, 3.0], 'BBB': [18.0, 4.0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `collections.defaultdict` instead of a regular dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

sums = defaultdict(float)
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file):
        sums[row[0]] += sum(float(elem) for elem in row[1:])

print(sums)  # -> defaultdict(<type 'float'>, {'AAA': 30.5, 'BBB': 18.0})
```